# Displaying WPF ProgressBar window in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to display a simple WPF Window with an `Indeterminate="True"` progress bar when running time consuming tasks.

I've implemented my solution following [this](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/) example by - Reed Copsey.

Once the process is complete I need to close the Window.
My guess was that to achieve this I would either need to kill the thread or close the view(window).

Unfortunately both ways give me the following errors:

1)Calling `Abort()` on a thread:

The window is closed, which is correct, but I'm still getting the following error:

Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

2)`View.Close()`:

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The required logic needs to be implemented in the `StopThread()` method, any idea what I could do to elegantly close the Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;

namespace ProgressBar
{
    public class ProgressBarViewModel
    {
        public DelegateCommand<object> CloseCommand { get; set; }
        Thread newWindowThread;

        string _closeButton;
        public string CloseButton 
        {
            get { return _closeButton; }
            set { _closeButton = value; }
        }

        ProgressBarView _view;
        public ProgressBarView View
        {
            get { return _view; }
            set { _view = value; }
        }

        public ProgressBarViewModel(ProgressBarView view)
        {
                CloseButton = "Close";
                CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(CloseForm);

                View = view;
                View.Closing +=new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(View_Closing);
                View.DataContext = this;
        }

        public void View_Closing(object sender,CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            StopThread();
        }

        public void CloseForm(object p)
        {
            StopThread();
        }

        private void StopThread()
        {
            try
            {
                //View.Close();
                newWindowThread.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
                //Getting an error when attempting to end the thread:
                //Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack
            }
        }

        public void ShowProgress()
        {
                newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    ProgressBarView tempWindow = new ProgressBarView();
                    tempWindow.DataContext = this;
                    tempWindow.Show();
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                }));

                newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
                newWindowThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is encapsulate your operation within its own class, and make it raise an event when it's completed (or you want to close the view)

The event handler will need to use the `Dispatcher` to run the `close()` in the same thread as the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a BackgroundWorker for this operation?  You can respond to the RunWorkerCompleted event to close the view.

```
public void YourFunction(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
      {
         ...do your long running operation
      };

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
      { 
         dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...close your view here);
      }

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, getting the same error as when I try to call View.Close(); Any other ideas?

Comment: @Deni...Are you debugging a Release build ("code is optimized") by any chance?  This may be related to Visual Studio.

Comment: @Deni...If the BGW wasn't created on the UI thread, then you'll need to pass in the Dispatcher and close you view from it.  Do you get the RunWorkerCompleted event to fire?